# prevent google from getting wrong keywords

Tags: seo, keyword

I have a website in persian language , google had got wrong redundant keyword on my website as the top rank keyword with maximum occurrence .

The keyword is 'های' . that's the sign of addition in persian language.

how do i prevent it from happening ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is not a programming topic. Try at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use more other keywords in your content to build your semantic core and change the TOP keywords list. This is the best way.

I would not worry about what you ask.